# How to make a menu like the main menu "Windows Phone"

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, user-interface

I want to have this effect when I touch a menu item in it, it go backward or go back from where I touch it
like in this example

[image]

where the one in the left is a normal state, the right when I click in the right corner if the item.

any help !!

Comment: The pictures look the same to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `TiltEffect` from `Silverlight Toolkit`. You can download it from codeplex

Comment: thx a lot, my tool kit version didn't have it, but I found the new one